# TFS Build Definitions: Use complex patterns in branch filter for triggering build

Tags: tfs

In TFS it is possible to set the trigger of a build definition to a specific branch (e.g. `master`). It is also possible to use patterns like so `features/*` in order to execute the build whenever there was a push to a branch underneath `features/`.

This already worked for me. In my use case now I want to trigger the build whenever there was a push to a branch with a specific version number in it.

E.g. `Bugs/BUG1234/BUG1234_v1.2`

I already tried things like `**/*_v1.2`, but it didn't work.
Did I miss something, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible for now, CI filter does not support such complex patterns. Please see [Continuous integration (CI)-Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers#continuous-integration-ci) for details.

As a workaround you can add multiple filters with the paths wich include the specific version number in it.

E.g.:

- `Include` `Bugs/BUG1234/BUG1234_v1.2`
- `Include` `Bugs/BUG5678/BUG5678_v1.2`
- `Include` `Bugs/BUG910/BUG910_v1.2`

However the requirement makes sense, I have submitted a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33604345-improve-continuous-integration-path-filtering-with) for you to suggest the feature. You can go and vote it up to push the Dev team to achieve that in future.